# Error while calling protected function of base class

Tags: c++, function, class, inheritance, member-functions

I am a beginner in C++. I am working on inheritance. In my code, when I try to call the member function of the base class from the derived class, i get the error `statement cannot resolve address of overloaded function`. I have applied the scope operator and the member function of the base class is protected, so that the derived do not have problem to access the functions. What am I doing wrong here? Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;
class Employee
{
private:
    char *emp_name;
    int emp_code;
    char *designation;

protected:
    Employee(char *name ="",int code = 0,char *des = "", int nlength=1, int dlength=1): emp_code(code)
    {
        emp_name = new char[nlength+1];
        strncpy(emp_name,name,nlength);

        designation = new char[dlength+1];
        strncpy(designation,des,nlength);
    }

    ~Employee()
    {
        delete[] emp_name;
        delete[] designation;
    }

    char* GetName()
    {
        return emp_name;
    }

    int GetCode()
    {
        return emp_code;
    }

    char* GetDes()
    {
        return designation;
    }
};

class Work: public Employee
{
private:
    int age;
    int year_exp;

public:
    Work(char *name ="", int code = 0, char *des = "", int nlength=1, int dlength=1, int w_age=0, int w_exp=0):Employee(name,code,des,nlength,dlength),age(w_age),year_exp(w_exp)
    {
    }

    void GetName()
    {
        Employee::GetName;
    }

    void GetCode()
    {
        Employee::GetCode;
    }

    void GetDes()
    {
        Employee::GetDes;
    }

    int GetAge()
    {
        return age;
    }

    int GetExp()
    {
        return year_exp;
    }

};

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    Work e1("Kiran",600160,"Implementation Specialist", strlen("Kiran"),strlen("Implementation Specialist"),24,5);

    cout << "Name: " << e1.GetName() << endl;
    cout << "Code: " << e1.GetCode() << endl;
    cout << "Designation: " << e1.GetDes() << endl;
    cout << "Age: " << e1.GetAge() << endl;
    cout << "Experience: " << e1.GetExp() << endl;
}
```

Also, I get the error `no-match for operator<<`. I am not printing any class . I am just calling the function of the derived class here.

Comment: `Employee::GetCode` doesn't call anything. `Employee::GetCode()` does.

Comment: `e1.GetName()` doesn't return any value (the return type of `Work::GetName` is `void`), so it's not clear what it is you are trying to print.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted already, the derived class `Work::GetName` is `void` so it's not returning any value. You could change that to:

```
class Work: public Employee
{
//...
public:
//...
    char *GetName()
    {
        return Employee::GetName();
    }
```

Or, if you just want to reuse the base class `Employee::GetName()` but make it public in the derived class, all you need to do is re-declare it as public in `Work`.

```
class Work: public Employee
{
//...
public:
//...
    using Employee::GetName; // <--- this re-declares the inherited GetName() as public
```

---

[EDIT] Changed the "re-declare" code to follow current C++ best practices, thanks @AlanStokes for the comment. Specifically, "access declarations" like the one originally used

```
    Employee::GetName; // <--- this re-declares the inherited GetName() as public
```

have been deprecated since C++98 in favor of "using declarations" with the same effect.

```
    using Employee::GetName; // <--- this re-declares the inherited GetName() as public
```

Comment: The modern syntax is `using Employee::GetName;`. The version without `using` is called an *access declaration*  and has been deprecated for nearly 20 years.

Answer (score 0):

C++ does *not* allow refering to members just naming them. You'll either need to take their address like `&Employee::GetDes` or you'll need to call them like `Employee::GetDes()`. You also might want to make sure you are actually returning the result but merely calling the member would work although it is unlikely to yield the desired result.